# Widget on the right side of the page overlaps with the left side

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I added the mailchimp widget to the right column of my blog. But for some reason, it overlaps with the main content of the blog.

Here is a screenshot of what happens[image]

Would anyone know why this happens and how to stop it from happening?

Thank you!

Comment: If I were a gamblin man I would bet on it being a CSS issue. Can you link your website? Add some relevant code?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thank you for your response. The site is http://fromdiettolifestyle.com/

Comment: Also, I don't see the overlap when I visit the site, but the client does see it, and the screenshot is from their screen.

Comment: I see it in the latest version of chrome. `.site-main .sidebar-container` is positioned absolute so it's going to overlay anything with a lower `z-index` may be beneficial to look into that.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thank you. I have not edited Wordpress css much recently. Which file should I edit? Is there are wordpress.css ? Or another css? And how do I best navigate to it?

Comment: Is this a default version of the 2013 theme? You may want to [google around](http://goo.gl/xd78B8) looks like this is a semi-common problem. You'll want to look for `style.css` or maybe just convert to the latest [2014 theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Twenty_Fourteen)

Comment: CSS is off topic. This question should be better asked at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)